# I have added the link to a puzzle which I have asked in the math site.i will be glad if anyone helps me with this

Tags: pattern, visual, connections-puzzle

Please go through the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1961818/376925) which has my question. All the details I've included there. The first row is question and the second one options. **Which comes next in this sequencing question?**

**Details imported from link**

> This question(first row cited as A B C D) contains 4 patterns and I want to know among the options given(the second row with pics cited as 12 3 4) which one comes next after the last in the sequencing.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is

> 1

Because

> The number of 'V's that flip each step alternate between 2 and 4. Therefore, the next step will have 3 'V's pointing in, and 2 'V's pointing out. (1) is the only option that fits this.

Comment: Yea 1 is the option given in the key.but I'm still confused about how did you explain the C D sequence in the question.its like being rotated.i don't get you :/

Comment: I don't see it as rotated, but as the right and bottom-right 'V' both being flipped.

Comment: start with picture A, and at the bottom left "V".  first flip two "V"s moving counterclockwise, so you flip bottom-left and bottom-right, to get to picture B.  then continue moving counterclockwise and flipping: flip 4 "V"s, ending at bottom-left "V" to give you picture C; then flip two more (to get picture D), then four more (pic E), then two more. you'll end there after flipping the top "V", leaving you with picture (1).